# Creating a 'join' table - sqlite3

Tags: join, sqlite

I think I'm pretty close on this one, but can't get it to click.

I've got two simple tables set up.

Table A:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
first_name TEXT,
last_name TEXT,
email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password TEXT NOT NULL,
create_time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I've got two rows of data populating correctly in Table A.

Table B:

```
CREATE TABLE address(
   ...> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> street_address_1 TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...> street_address_2 TEXT,
   ...> street_address_3 TEXT,
   ...> city TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...> state TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...> zip TEXT NOT NULL);
```

And I've successfully imported a CSV file into that table.

I'm trying to create a 3rd table that joins Table A to Table B with the use of Foreign Keys.

I can create the table with the code below, but when I try to select the table, I'm getting a blank, which means I'm obviously doing something wrong. I'm expecting to see data where the two tables overlap on mutual Id numbers, i.e. where the ID from customer = Id from address I'd like to see the data from both tables for those rows appear in Table C.

Table C (the join table):

```
CREATE TABLE customer_address(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INTEGER,
address_id INTEGER,
first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
email TEXT NOT NULL,
password TEXT NOT NULL,
street_address_1 TEXT NOT NULL,
street_address_2 TEXT,
street_address_3 TEXT,
city TEXT NOT NULL,
state TEXT NOT NULL,
zip TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address(id)
);
```

Thanks!

I imported the data to the address table using this:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import address.csv address
```

I manually typed in data to the first table using this:

```
insert into customer(first_name, last_name, email, password)
values('Ad','Mac','a.Mac@gmail.com','Mab'),('Brian','Obrien','bob@example.com','123456');
```

Comment: Can we see the query you're using to pull data from the join table?

Comment: select * from customer_address;

Comment: Oh, well then it looks like the data isn't going into the table in the first place. Can we see your method of inserting the records? Is this being done manually?

Comment: sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import address.csv address

Comment: And what does that csv file look like? If you're just doing `select *` then something is probably going wrong with the insert. Are you possibly trying to insert into Table C before the other two? Then there might be a foreign key violation.

Comment: I think both tables are valid as I can select * for both of them and see both tables, independently, populating correctly.  My order is: created/inserted table A, created/imported data table B, attempting to create/join table C

Answer (score 1):

Don't duplicate the data in your join table (often called a bridge table). This should do for Table C:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_address(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INTEGER,
address_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address(id));
```

Duplicating columns is bad practice because it 1)defeats the purpose of using a relational model; 2)can lead to conflicting records if information is updated or deleted in one table, but not another.

Furthermore, you shouldn't have street_address_1, street_address_2, street_address_3 all in the same table. That's a violation of First Normal Form. Think of it this way, can a person have more than three addresses? Can they have two addresses in different cities? Do all three of those addresses have the same zip?

Comment: I think the intent of the multiple address fields is to account for an address with multiple parts such as JoJo, 413 S Thames Street, Apartment 4, Floor 4, Baltimore, MD, 21222

Comment: This is very helpful as I didn't know about duplicating columns.  Table C isn't joining yet, but I'll keep trying to reconfigure.